# Is Branding / Marketing part of UX?

Tags: discussion

This is in regards to:
[Which language to use for an European brand name?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53855/which-language-to-use-for-an-european-brand-name)

Similar to the other thread regarding copy, do we also consider branding or marketing questions also part of User Experience? Is there another Q&A board for this?

In the same vein, do we not also count proper coding as part of the Experience of Programming Users?

Where do we draw this line?

Answer (score 1):

We can't. As SE networks have expanded, we've invariably partitioned up the topics perhaps to a fault and we're now stuck with overlap.

I think branding is as much UX as it is Graphic Design, for instance.

And good code certainly plays into UX, so wouldn't say that's completely off topic either.

But I think we have to draw lines somewhere, even if they are fuzzy and somewhat arbitrary.

It looks like there was a marketing SE site proposed: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51786/marketing

Currently it's in closed status, though.

However, there's now a digital marketing proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65811/digital-marketing

Maybe that question fits there best?

(Crazy Idea that might be terrible: Perhaps this site should be 'UX and Digital Marketing'. It'd be nice to see those two disciplines come together since they often need to work hand-in-hand to succeed.)

Comment: The scope of UX is extremely broad because it's not just interaction design on screens. We are also accepting user experience in the non-digital realm as well (For Example, ATMs, Parking Meters, and Elevators.) We are all artists, content creators, analysts, developers, users, ethnographers, anthropologists, psychologists, researchers, communicators (to name a few) as well as Digital Marketers.

Answer (score 0):

Your brand is your user experience.

Comment: Or maybe it is the otherway around, you User Experience is you Brand

Comment: While I agree totally, this is likely too broadly encompassing for UX.se as by rights we'd have to bring in a lot more than just marketing if we use that definition.